# -bash: <npm-package>:command not found [Mac]

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, npm, terminal

I've been installing a lot of packages from Github via NPM. For example, Moneda.

When I try to run the package, I get

```
-bash: moneda: command not found
```

This happens for every package I install with NPM from Github.

I've tried resetting bash completely.

This is what I get when typing `echo $PATH`:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I've tried uninstalling brew, npm, node and reinstalling them all, still not working. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: What is this syntax you're using for installing the modules? My first guess is that you're not using the global flag `-g` (which is necessary to use NPM modules as a binary file that you can use from the terminal)

Answer (score 2):

The bigger question is : *where does npm install its packages?* If the configuration directory of `npm` is `~/.npm-global`, then you have to update your `PATH`

```
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

More information can be found [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders)

Comment: I had to do `export PATH=~/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH`